# OOP mysqli database functions

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am a beginner in OOP in PHP and I am trying to play with my code. So first thing I wanted to do is to write one basic class with connect and insert functions for database. So my desired situation is this:

-I wanna create on class which will controll connect and insert functions. The problem is, my $connect variable isn't working from another function, so what could I do to make that possible? 
You will understand more by the code provided.

```
<?php

class DB {
protected $dbhost = 'localhost';
protected $dbuser = 'root';
protected $dbpass = '';
protected $dbname = 'newdb';

public function connect()
{
    $connect = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);

    if($connect->error)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "connected";
    }
}

public function insert($name, $second)
{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO posts (name, second) VALUES ('$name', '$second')"; 

    if ($connect->query($insert) === TRUE) 
    {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
}
}
require_once 'classes/DB.php';

$db = new DB;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $second = $_POST['second'];

    $db->insert($name, $second);
}

?>


<form method="POST">
    Add smth<input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Also omg<input type="text" name="second"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What about passing as a parameter?

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't know the proper usage. That's why I am searching for help.

Comment: `$connect` is in the local scope of that function. You also will be open to SQL injections with this code. You should look at using parameterized queries, best to learn it when you are starting out. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Try to make a singleton class and you need to add `$connect` as a property of the class.

Comment: I'll try further on. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$connect` as a property of your class, so you may reuse it everywhere within the class using `$this->connect`:

```
class DB
{
    protected $dbhost = 'localhost';
    protected $dbuser = 'root';
    protected $dbpass = '';
    protected $dbname = 'newdb';
    protected $connect;

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->connect = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);

        if ($this->connect->error)
        {
            echo "Failed to connect";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "connected";
        }
    }

    public function insert($name, $second)
    {
        $insert = "INSERT INTO posts (name, second) VALUES ('$name', '$second')";

        if ($this->connect->query($insert) === TRUE)
        {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you executing?

Comment: I updated the code. Those are two different files, but it's okay, you understand. Scroll down and see it.

Comment: actually it was my bad, you were right. I forgot to execute the connect() function. Thank you my friend. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten your class for a bit, so you can insert your database settings in the constructor. So it really is a object, and you can use multiple databases. What you did wrong in your class was using the variable $connect without declaring it into a variable usable in the whole class.

**The class**

```
<?php

class DB {
    protected $dbhost;
    protected $dbuser;
    protected $dbpass;
    protected $dbname;
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname)
    {
        $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
        $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
        $this->dbpass = $dbpass;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;

        $connection = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
        if($connection->error)
            die('Could not connect with the database!');

        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->__construct($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
    }

    public function insert($name, $second)
    {
        $insert = "INSERT INTO posts (name, second) VALUES ('$name', '$second')"; 

        if ($this->connection->query($insert) === TRUE) 
        {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
$db = new DB('localhost', 'root', '', 'newdb');
$db->insert('name', 'second');
```

I hope this helps you in your journal through OOP, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Yeah this works also. I fixed it 2 minutes ago haha. But anyway, thank you for helping. I appreciate.